# Organizing html data scraped using BeautifulSoup and Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I would like to take the dates and setlists from this page https://www.zappateers.com/fzshows/78.html
and then organize it so it looks like this:

1978 08 26 The Purple Lagoon

1978 08 26 Dancin' Fool

1978 08 26 Easy Meat

1978 08 26 Honey Don't You Want A Man Like Me?

etc.  so the date of the show and the song played appear next to each other in columns.

I have this python code

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
source = requests.get('https://www.zappateers.com/fzshows/78.html').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')    

for heading in soup.find_all([ "h4", "p"]):
    
    print(heading.text.strip())
```

that extracts the h4 tag (the date and venue) and the p tag (setlists).

But it just prints it out like this:

1978 08 26 - Festplatz Friedrichsau, Ulm, Germany
Parts of the show were pro-shot, see "Ein Leben als Extravaganza".
The Purple Lagoon, Dancin' Fool, Easy Meat, Honey Don't You Want A Man Like Me?,

What can I do to organize it in columns as indicated above?  Thank you

Comment: Is the link correct? It won't load for me.

Comment: songs are in p tag with class attribute `setlist`. However there are dates with missing songs e.g. 1978 09 08 and this makes it tricky. One can not just iterate looking for `h4` and then `p class=setlist` tags

Comment: The URL is correct.  It's working for me.  Anyone else have trouble?

Comment: Also note 1978 10 15 where you have 3 p tags with class=setlist, one for early show and one for late show

Answer (score 2):

This should help you:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

source = requests.get('https://www.zappateers.com/fzshows/78.html').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')

text = []
dates = []

headings = soup.find_all('h4')

for index,p in enumerate(soup.find_all('p', class_ = "setlist")):
    h = headings[index]
    for x in range(len(p.text.strip().split(','))):
        if '-' in h.text:
            dates.append(h.text.strip().split('-')[0].strip())
    if '-' in h.text:
        text.append(p.text.strip().split(','))

text = [item for sublist in text for item in sublist]

df = pd.DataFrame([dates,text]).T
df.columns = ['Date','Title']
print(df)
```

Output:

```
           Date                                      Title
0    1978 08 26                          The Purple Lagoon
1    1978 08 26                               Dancin' Fool
2    1978 08 26                                  Easy Meat
3    1978 08 26        Honey Don't You Want A Man Like Me?
4    1978 08 26                            Keep It Greasey
..          ...                                        ...
462  1978 10 31                              Suicide Chump
463  1978 10 31                       Improvisations In Q*
464  1978 10 31               Why Does It Hurt When I Pee?
465  1978 10 31   Improvisations (incl. Hail Caesar Theme)
466  1978 10 31                              Magic Fingers

[467 rows x 2 columns]
```

You can also send these details to a `csv` file by adding this line to your code:

```
df.to_csv('D:\\Songs.csv',index = False)
```

Screenshot of `csv` file:

[image]

Comment: There is problem with certain dates missing `<p calss=setlist>` tag and this messup the songs. e.g. print full dataframe and look at 1978 09 08. It shows the songs for 1978 09 09

Comment: Also note 1978 10 15 where you have 3 p tags with class=setlist, one for early show and one for late show

Comment: Thank you so much!  Works perfectly. I tried using a df but couldn't work out the different lengths of the arrays.  I will now have your code to learn form.  I wish I could vote this up more than just once.  Thanks again

Comment: @Sushil hi - been trying to work out some issues.  When the <h4> tag uses the class="wrongdate", those get pulled in and mess up the songlists..  (I think buran mentioned this above).  I changed this line
headings = soup.find_all('h4') to headings = soup.find_all('h4',class_= None) and it works when the URL is https://www.zappateers.com/fzshows/72.html but not on the original above.
The other issue is when there is an h5 tag that says "Early Show" or "Late Show", etc.  They are not being added to the array.  I tried to get this working but failed miserably. Help please?

Comment: To better illustrate, the data I want to scrape looks like this:
<h4> DATE </h4>

<h5 TYPE </h5>

<h6 Length</h6>

<p class="setlist">SONGS </p>


I only want the h4, h5 and p data in the dataframe.  Not every show has an h5 tag and that's where it gets tricky, I guess.  When those are missing, the <h4> tags get scraped with the wrong <p> content so the songs from one show get added to a different show.

Comment: Ok...Will look into it.